# Java SnakeYAML error when converting yaml to class instance

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to convert the following yaml to class:

```
ability:
  name: my-ability-name!
  types:
    - source1
    - source2
  description: Description
  tags:
    - tag1
    - tag2
isActive: true
```

using the following code from SnakeYaml and [Jackson-dataformats-text](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-text) (yaml)

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new YAMLMapper();
MyClass xMyClass = mapper.readValue(yamlString, MyClass.class);
```

My class looks like this:

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class MyClass {
    private Abilities.AbilityDto ability;
    private boolean isActive;
}
```

My protobuf looks like this:

```
message AbilityDto {
  string id = 1;
  string name = 2;
  repeated string types = 3;
  optional string description = 4;
  repeated string tags = 5;
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Cannot find a deserializer for non-concrete Collection type [collection type; class com.google.protobuf.ProtocolStringList, contains [simple type, class java.lang.String]]
 at [Source: (StringReader); line: 1, column: 1]
```

I've tried the make the yaml as minimal as possible and removed many fields to check where the problem is, couldn't solve it.

Also tried formatting to a class using a different way:

```
  Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
MyClass xMyClass = yaml.loadAs(yamlString, MyClass.class);
```

Getting error:

```
Cannot create property=rule for JavaBean=io.avalor.....MyClass@24f47796
 in 'string', line 1, column 1:
    ability:
    ^
Cannot create property=name for JavaBean=
 in 'string', line 2, column 3:
      name: "my-ability-name!"
      ^
No writable property 'name' on class: io.avalor.protocol...AbilityDto
 in 'string', line 2, column 9:
      name: "my-ability-name!"
            ^

 in 'string', line 2, column 3:
      name: "my-ability-name!"
```

Comment: Well `com.google.protobuf.ProtocolStringList` is an interface and Jackson doesn't know how to construct an object satisfying that interface. Try `mapper.registerSubtypes(com.google.protobuf.LazyStringArrayList.class);`, not sure if that's enough to fix it.

Comment: what is "message" AbilityDto ?